# Decimal pipe or round pipe is not working in Angular4

Tags: angular, decimal, rounding

I am simply trying to achieve this calculation:

```
{{(this.buyForm.value.rate * this.buyForm.value.Units)}}
```

Now, rate will have values in decimal places like 0.00003095 * 0.03004 like this.

Now with multiplication, I would like to control it with 8 decimal points.

I tried using decimal pipe like:

```
{{(this.buyForm.value.rate * this.buyForm.value.Units)|number:'1.8-8'}}
```

`{{(this.buyForm.value.rate * this.buyForm.value.Units)|round}}` but nothing is working in my case.

Comment: "Nothing is working" ... do you get a wrong output or an exception ?

Comment: I get 0 value only

Comment: Have you tried it with no pipe at all, just to make sure the value isn't actually 0?

Comment: yes, it comes with uncontrolled decimal points

Comment: This seems to work okay for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzsbxp

Comment: like this 4.4702e-12

Comment: what addition code should I provide to investigate more

Comment: A number as small as 4.4702e-12 would come out as 0 (well, 0.00000000) rounded to 8 decimal places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to add `this` to bind your properties in the HTML template :

Try

`{{(buyForm.value.rate * buyForm.value.Units)|number:'1.8-8'}}`

instead of

`{{(this.buyForm.value.rate * this.buyForm.value.Units)|number:'1.8-8'}}`